# Javascript module pattern, nested functions, and sub modules

Tags: javascript, module

I am trying to wrap my head around javascript modules, but I'm unsure how to split up a module into further sub modules. I have read that nested functions are not really a great idea, due to performance, so how do I break up a function in a module? For example, lets say I have the following module:

```
var Editor = {};

Editor.build = (function () {
    var x = 100;
    return {
        bigFunction: function () {
            // This is where I need to define a couple smaller functions 
            // should I create a new module for bigFunction? If so, should it be nested in Editor.build somehow?
        }
    };
})();
```

bigFunction is only related to Editor.build. Should I attach the smaller functions that make up bigFunction to the prototype bigFunction object? I'm not even sure if that would make sense.

```
var Editor = {};

Editor.build = (function () {
    var x = 100;
    return {
        bigFunction: function () {
            bigFunction.smallFunction();
            bigFunction.prototype.smallFunction = function(){ /*do something */ };   
            // not sure if this even makes sense
        }
    };
})();
```

Can someone please throw me in the right direction here? There is so much misleading information online, and would just like a definite guide on how to deal with this sort of modularization.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet I use to make names for an input:

```
    var dynamicCounter = 0;
    //custom dropdown names
    var createContainerNames = function () {
        function Names() {
            this.id = "Tasks_" + dynamicCounter + "__ContainerId";
            this.name = "Tasks[" + dynamicCounter + "].ContainerId";
            this.parent = "task" + dynamicCounter + "Container";
        }
        Names.prototype = { constructor: Names };
        return function () { return new Names(); };
    } ();
```

And then I use it:

```
    var createdNames = createContainerNames();
    var createdId = createdNames.id;
    dynamicCounter++;
    var differentNames = createContainerNames();
    var differentId = differentNames.id;
```

Another approach would be to do this:

```
var NameModule = function(){

 //"private" namemodule variables
 var priv1 = "Hello";

 //"private namemodule methods
 function privMethod1(){
  //TODO: implement
 }

 //"public namemodule variables
 var pub1 = "Welcome";

 //"public" namemodule methods
 function PubMethod(){
  //TODO: pub
 } 

 return {
  pub1 : pub1,
  PubMethod: PubMethod
 };
```

and then to use it

```
var myPubMethod = new NameModule();
myPubMethod.PubMethod();
var pubVar = myPubMethod.pub1;
```

**EDIT**

You could also take this approach:

```
var mod = function(){
 this.modArray = [];
};

mod.prototype = {

 //private variables
 modId: null,

 //public method
 AddToArray: function (obj) {
    this.modArray.push(obj);
 }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem particularly useful to hold the constructor and its prototype in a closure, it means that you can't easily extend or modify the prototype later. Hard to see any benefit to standard function declarations and prototype assignment. The module pattern is really about modules, i.e. one–of objects, not constructors.

Comment: @RobG - The first is definitely more of a standalone. The difference between that and a standard function is going to be that you get back unique objects. The second approach is more inline with a module pattern. I could put a third one in which uses prototype as an extension approach.

Comment: @RobG - How do you implement your modules in javascript?

Comment: I use the module pattern only where I need to keep "private" variables and functions in closures (e.g. a helper method that is specifically for the module it's enclosed in). If I don't have any, I don't use the module pattern, though I might use an IIFE to conditonally create functions (e.g. with feature detection) where closures are an artifact rather than a feature. Horses for courses.